# Huntress doubleshot?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

Today I noticed that my Huntress' weapon some times fire off two shots/arrow at the same time, so I have a few questions about it:

- Is this intentionally?
- If so, what is the percentage of this happening?
- Does it consume two, or only one ammo?
- Can it also happen with piercing shots?

Comment: Is this possibly a property of the particular weapon you're using? Can you post a screenshot of your detailed weapon info?

Comment: This happens on most weapons.  I've seen it plenty of times.  I don't know if it's a bug, but it is pretty frequent.  It happens for me only on the "first shot", in a set of shots.  So if I stop shooting, when it starts again is when it happens for me.  Not every time.  But like 30-40% of the time at least, from what I've seen.  That's not an accurate %.  It never happens for me with piercing shots.  But I can't definitively answer the q's so, a comment is all I can offer.

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes Nope, it has happened at least once with every weapon I've used. Maybe not the default one, however, that's not counted as a weapon in the inventory screen.

Comment: I'm pretty sure its a bug, I've only noticed it happen after a reload most often.  I wouldn't count on it either way.  Also, as for piercing shots, I haven't seen it happen.  I tend to spam piercing shot a lot and would've noticed if it did it twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial 'Double Shot' you can get off a huntress weapon (it has not appeared to matter so far) appears to be a bug. It seems tied to the timing of firing your weapon, reloading the weapon and then firing it again, as if the 'time between shots' was not reset after you were done reloading.